# HTACCESS: How to mask redirected URL and keep "friendly" URL in URL bar

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a RewriteRule that is working perfectly. The url format, using aaa, bbb, and ccc for simplicity and the root being 'aaa' on my localhost, and [[SOME NUMBER]] and [[SOME OTHER NUMBER]] simply standing for integers of any length, is:

```
aaa/bbb.php?bbb_id=[[SOME NUMBER]]#ccc.php?ccc_id=[[SOME OTHER NUMBER]]
```

I map from this "friendly" URL format:

```
aaa/bbb[[SOME NUMBER]]/ccc[[SOME OTHER NUMBER]]
```

...using this rewrite rule, which works perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^aaa([0-9-]+)/bbb([0-9-]+)/?$ /aaa.php?aaa_id=$1#bbb.php?bbb_id=$2 [NE]
```

(Notice I need the [NE] because of the # in the URL.)

So:

```
aaa/bbb8/ccc232
```

...becomes/redirects to:

```
aaa/bbb.php?bbb_id=8#ccc.php?ccc_id=232
```

This works perfectly. But what is the RewriteCond that would allow the "friendly" URL to remain in the URL bar once the redirect occurs? I've studied other examples online and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `[L]` to the rewrite rule to stop processing after it matches. It should do an internal redirect and you can use `aaa/bbb8/ccc232` in the address bar.

```
RewriteRule ^aaa([0-9-]+)/bbb([0-9-]+)/?$ /aaa.php?aaa_id=$1#bbb.php?bbb_id=$2 [NE,L]
```

Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: Thanks...I edited the rule as you suggest. Strangely, though, when I run it now, the screen becomes blank; when I view the source, it's all there...so it processed the php files correctly, and the URL does remain aaa/bbb8/ccc232 in the the status bar...but nothing is displayed. When I refresh the screen, it's still blank, yet the source is still accurate and aaa/bbb8/ccc232 remains in the URL bar. Any clue why this would happen?

Comment: One more thing: adding R=301 to the flags (so they become [NE,L,R=301]) allows the page to display, but then the URL bar displays the "unfriendly" URL of aaa/bbb.php?bbb_id=8#ccc.php?ccc_id=232 (using the example numbers we were discussing). What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the URL *remain* aaa/bbb8/ccc232 after the page has been processed and displayed; I don't want the redirected php code to display; I want the aaa/bbb8/ccc232 to remain in the URL bar once the redirection is accomplished.

Comment: @Tom I provided that to you. That is how you `internally` redirect.  You can not use the R flag at all which means **R**edirect or it will do an external redirect and show the php URL. A blank page usually indicates you have a PHP error. You need to debug and make sure you are getting the $_GET array by testing in PHP. Also you need to check your error_log. I can't stress that enough. Error log is typically the most helpful in finding the error.

Comment: Sorry, no dice. The error_log shows *no* errors when executing the script. I've verified this by wiping it clean of previous errors and starting afresh. Could anything else be causing this behavior? Again: the correct HTML is server to the browser window, but nothing displays (I've examined the source code fed to the browser when using the dynamic vs static addresses, and the resulting HTML is exactly the same.)

Comment: I believe the issue may have to do with references to posted values that Javascript on the page cannot access precisely because the page is being fetched via a static URL that does not contain them. Javascript is too long to post here, so I've uploaded the file in question here as plain text: 

https://home.comcast.net/~tom.brodhead/problem.txt

I'll appreciate any comments/insights/suggestions; the Javascript is at the bottom of the code.